# How can the Values of a Field be represented by alias? (generally in SQL, or Apache-Superset / Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

**How can the Values of a Field be represented by alias?**
**(generally in SQL, or Apache-Superset / Postgres)**
++ I have a Filed with "w" and "m" values, and I need to show them as "female" and "male", for example..
++ any clue (at Query / Superset -level) is appreciated..

Comment: Hi, please read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want a `case` expression?

```
select (case when field = 'w' then 'female' when field = 'm' then 'male' else field end) as new_value
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon mentioned you do it with a case and in Superset you do it in the expression of a column or you can create a virtual column as in this screenshoot.

[image]